# asp.net + integrating Facebook event and joining

Tags: facebook

I intend to integrate the Facebook event on my website using the Event api, however I understand that we can't join the event through my website, correct me if I am wrong. What is the best way to go about this because if possible, I prefer not to have my user exit from my website, what I can think of is to display the Facebook Event page itself on a iFrame or something when the user clicks on any of the events link on my website. Anyone can advise if there's a better way of dealing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Correcting you where you’re wrong: Yes, you can RSVP to an event via API. How – see docs please.

Comment: I know we can invite friends to join but I don't see it in the API where I can directly join the event.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#attending – D’oh!